# RexEx not matching the last group

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following RegEx

```
(.*?)(>=|<=|~|!=|=|!~|>|<| IS | IS NOT | WAS | WAS IN | WAS NOT | WAS NOT IN | CHANGED | OR | AND | IN | NOT IN )
```

It's matching almost all of my test text:

```
project=blah AND blah=something OR issuetype!="blah" AND someissue IN somefunction("blah") OR blahing <= "something"
```

It's just not matching that last "something" string. I understand why, but I'm struggling to put something into the expression which will capture the end value.

Comment: Just as a tangent - it seems that you’re trying to parse SQL. A quick search reveals that there are potent SQL parsers around for .NET, which may be a better longterm approach to your problem.

Comment: For example, does this `| WAS NOT IN |` mean it requires a space before and after `WAS NOT IN`. Likewise the other text alternations ?

Answer (score 0):

I think seems to have done the trick

```
((.*?)(>=|<=|~|!=|=|!~|>|<| IS | IS NOT | WAS | WAS IN | WAS NOT | WAS NOT IN | CHANGED | OR | AND | IN | NOT IN ))|(.*?)$
```